# css box-sizing in ie8 standards compliant mode

Tags: internet-explorer, css, internet-explorer-8

I am aware that internet explorer has traditionally implemented css box sizing "wrong" by including padding and border widths in the total box width. IE8+ "fixes" this box sizing when a page is rendered in standards compliance mode and implements CSS3 box-sizing using the -ms-box-sizing property.

But here's something fun. The following code renders a few divs with various width + padding + border + box-sizing combinations:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        div { margin-bottom: 1em; background-color: #5555e9; }
        
        #test1 { width: 500px; }
        #test2 { width: 500px; padding: 10px; }
        #test3 { width: 500px; padding: 10px; border: 5px solid red; }
        #test4 { width: 500px; padding: 10px; border: 5px solid red;
            -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test1">Hello World!</div>
    <div id="test2">Hello World!</div>
    <div id="test3">Hello World!</div>
    <div id="test4">Hello World!</div>
</body>
```

In IE8 quirks mode, all the divs output with the same 500px width, as expected given IE's quirky calculation of box size:

[image: html code rendered in IE8 quirks mode]

But if I add the following doctype declaration to render in IE8 standards compliance mode:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

the output becomes this:

[image]

Notice the last box is rendered with the same dimensions as the third box, even though the box-sizing property is set to border-box every which way using css. I really want IE8 to use the border-box method in standards compliance mode, but given this test I don't know how to make it happen. Does anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Knyri's answer:

The problem is my IE8 browser instance defaulted to rendering in IE 7 standards mode, not 8. (IE7 does not support CSS3 box-sizing.) I was able to fix the issue by forcing the page to render in IE 8 standards compliance mode. I added the following to my html head tag:

```
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8"/>
```

It must come before other tags in the html head tag except for title and other meta tags. This results in the following rendering:

[image]

As you can see, the first three boxes render with content-box box-sizing (the W3C standard), and the fourth renders with border-box because it was explicitly set using CSS.

Answer (score 1):

In standards mode it follows the correct box model.

```
---------------------------------------------
|  margin                                   |
|  ---------------------------------------  |
|  |Border                               |  |
|  |  ---------------------------------- |  |
|  |  |padding                         | |  |
|  |  | -----------------------------  | |  |
|  |  | |Content                     | | |  |
|  |  | |____________________________| | |  |
|  |  |________________________________| |  |
|  |_____________________________________|  |
|___________________________________________|
```

The width and height in your CSS are affecting the width and height of the content area in standards mode and the width and height of the border box when in quirks mode.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Knyri. However, what about the very last box, where I apply -ms-box-sizing: border-box? I expected it to follow the border-box model instead of content-box (which is the standard). From what I've read on various sources it IE8 should support the box-sizing property, but that doesn't seem to be happening in standards mode.

Comment: Odd. When I run IE9 in IE8 browser mode and IE8 standards document mode it works fine. In case you're not aware, hit F12 in IE for the nifty, albeit lacking, developer tools. I use it mostly to see how my pages render in different versions of IE.

Comment: Oh ho! When I use the developer tools, I discovered my page is defaulting to IE 7 standards mode! When I change it to IE8, it works fine. I've been familiar with the developer tools, but not the ability to switch modes. Thanks!